# Are the Static Map API up to date?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

My question is :

When are the Static Map API synchronized with the current Google Maps DB?

I made a small code that gives me the following URL to a static map :

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=50.585606,+5.563505&zoom=17&scale=false&size=500x500&maptype=satellite&format=png&visual_refresh=true

But when you ask Google Maps to show you the actual reality, it gives you another picture, which is up to date ! (coords : 50.585606, 5.563505).

Please, consider my bad level in english.

Comment: I´m not sure about that, but If you take at the right corner on the bottom, you see that different data are used

Comment: The problem is both shows me "2016". Or the roads modification dated from like September 2015 :/ I had someone on the phone from Google how told me they update all the data every month. The fact is they didn't.

Comment: Yeah both are from 2016. But the static map say´s: "Aerodata International Surverys, DigitalGlobe......"Whereas on maps.google something else is displayed. Guess that is the problem. Google´s data are maybe up-to date. But the others are not

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thx for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** This seems to be [Issue 8910: Static map shows different satellite tiles than Google Maps](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8910). Please star that issue to keep track of interest on it, and to receive updates.

Imagery updates may not always be perfectly in sync, but at least you can subscribe to them in Google's [Follow Your World](https://followyourworld.appspot.com/) tool.

See also: [Issue 6908: Feature Request: Retrieve satellite photo tile date](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6908)